# Dishwasher pump is crackling [video]; is it obstructed or does it need to be replaced?

Tags: dishwasher, noise, pump

My dishwasher (Frigidaire Model FDB2000RFC1) is making a [loud clicking/cracking](https://plus.google.com/photos/+JasonFuller/albums/5980044465978156065/5980044472529547458?gpinv=AMIXal-HuFAgCBVrjklyw4EIqpHlHQfMSX7CYDW2wyP6eW0u9VFGElHAjnGT9JIf12L1JWGeASOzigx80S5Q4nqejzcQLxX-mca-ioMH1AIXGI85g2GsPA8&cfem=1)  sound when the drain pump is active.

#### Is it possible that there's just something in the pump that isn't being ejected properly?  or do I need a totally new pump?

Comment: Your link needs to be more specific. Without hearing anything, it could be something is just caught in the works. It would require disassembly to make a determination, it's difficult to tell by recorded sound. Inquire if you are able to return an unused pump for refund or not. It's nice to have options once you start taking things apart.

Comment: Now that the link works, it is as I suspected, I couldn't say one way or the other for sure. Maybe someone else is more confident with their audio diagnostic skills :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dismantled the "drain pump assembly" part making the noise and the solenoid and paddle flaps looked fine.  However when manually turning the flaps I could occasionally reproduce the slappy / crackling noise.

Upon further inspection, it was apparent that the seal the axel for the agitator had a small leak.  I ordered a new piece and sure enough, the sound is gone!